# 1.9 - Add custom column to Sales Order Create Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I've copied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php
```

To

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php
```

And added `->addAttributeToSelect('brand')` within `_prepareCollection()`

Within `_prepareColumns()` I have added:

```
$this->addColumn('brand', array(
  'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Brand'),
  'width'     => '80',
  'index'     => 'brand'
));
```

I now have the Brand ID in the Sales Order Create Grid.

However I want to see the brand name rather than ID (The brand is a dropdown within admin).

How do I display the option value rather than ID?
ie. "Brand Name" rather than "47"

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding the below to `_prepareColumns()`:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$values = array();
foreach ($options as $option){
  $values[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}

$this->addColumn('brand', array(
  'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Brand'),
  'width'     => '80',
  'index'     => 'brand',
  'type'      => 'options',
  'options'   => $values
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Inchoo [article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/) on extending the order grid. And on the Atwix blog there's an [article](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/) on adding a column from a different table.

You will be rewriting the `Mage_Adminhtml_Order_Grid` block class adding a column to the `_prepareColumns` method and extending the `_prepareCollection` method with your custom field